# using profile that assume role in aws-sdk (AWS JavaScript SDK)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs

Using the AWS SDK for JavaScript, I want to use a default profile that assumes the a role. This works perfectly with the AWS CLI. Using node.js with the SDK does not assume the role, but only uses credentials to the AWS account that the access key belongs to.
I've found this documentation but it does not deal with assuming a role: [Loading Credentials in Node.js from the Shared Credentials File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)

Any tips?

This is my config file:

```
[default]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Developer
source_profile = default
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, and I see the same problem using Python and Boto3 SDK.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the node.js client doesn't automatically assume roles.  If you want to assume those roles, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The CLI and SDK work differently, in that you must explicitly assume the role when using the SDK. The SDK doesn't automatically assume the role from the config as the CLI does.

After the role is assumed, the AWS.config must be updated with the new credentials.

This works for me:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

var sts = new AWS.STS();
sts.assumeRole({
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Developer',
  RoleSessionName: 'awssdk'
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) { // an error occurred
    console.log('Cannot assume role');
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else { // successful response
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I find this works for me the first time, but when I attempt to refresh the credentials, I get Access Denied. I put this code into a setInterval loop and on the second iteration it fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is that calling `AWS.config.update` isn't the right move in your use-case. The subsequent credentials probably don't have permission to assume the role.

Comment: This approach doesn't take in consideration the credential expiry. The sdk supports this out of the box. Look at @Kanak Singhal answer.

Comment: I wonder when AWS will start to add this hidden steps on their docs.

Answer (score 81):

**The right way to use multiple cross account roles in the code**:

Get the credentials for the cross account role with sts and use those credentials every time you need to get a service authenticated with that specific cross account role.

Example:

Create a function to get the cross account credentials like:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sts = new AWS.STS();

const getCrossAccountCredentials = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    const params = {
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Developer',
      RoleSessionName: `be-descriptibe-here-${timestamp}`
    };
    sts.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else {
        resolve({
          accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And then you can use it without problems like:

```
const main = async () => {
  // Get the Cross account credentials
  const accessparams = await getCrossAccountCredentials();
  // Get the ec2 service for current account
  const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
  // Get the ec2 service for cross account role
  const ca_ec2 = new AWS.EC2(accessparams);
  // Get the autoscaling service for current account
  const autoscaling = new AWS.AutoScaling();
  // Get the autoscaling service for cross account role
  const ca_autoscaling = new AWS.AutoScaling(accessparams);

  // This will describe instances within the cross account role
  ca_ec2.describeInstances(...) 

  // This will describe instances within the original account
  ec2.describeInstances(...)

  // Here you can access both accounts without issues.
}
```

Benefits:

- Does not change the credentials globally, so you can still target your own AWS account without having to backup the credentials in advance to restore it.
- Allows to control exactly what account you're targeting in every moment.
- Allows to handle multiple cross account roles and services.

**The wrong way**:

DO NOT USE `AWS.config.update` to override the global credentials `AWS.config.credentials`!!!

Override the global credentials is a bad practice!! This is same situation as @Brant's approved solution here but it is no good solution! Here is why:

```
const main = async () => {
  // Get the Cross account credentials
  const accessparams = await getCrossAccountCredentials();

  // Get the ec2 service for current account
  const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

  // Overwrite the AWS credentials with cross account credentilas
  AWS.config.update(accessparams);

  // Get the ec2 service for cross account role
  const ca_ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

  // This will describe instances within the cross account role
  ca_ec2.describeInstances(...) 

  // This will ALSO describe instances within the cross account role
  ec2.describeInstances(...)

  // WARNING: Here you only will access the cross account role. You may get
  // confused on what you're accessing!!!
}
```

Issues:

- Updating global `AWS.config.credentials` directly or by `AWS.config.update`, will override current credentials.
- Everything will point to that cross account role, even future service calls that you may not expect.
- To switch back to first account you may need to temporary backup `AWS.config.credentials` and update it again to restore it. It is hard to control when you use each account, it is hard to trace execution context, and easy to mess up by targeting the wrong account.

Again, DO NOT USE `AWS.config.update` to override the global credentials `AWS.config.credentials`!!!

**If you need to run the code entirely in another account**:

If you need to execute your code entirely for another account without switching between credentials. You can follow the advice from @Kanak Singhal and store the role_arn in the config file and add `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG="true"` to the environment variable along with `AWS_PROFILE="assume-role-profile"`.

Comment: This is a better solution! Thanks.

Comment: Is the expiration handled automatically or we need to handle it explicitly?

Comment: @user3324360 session duration and renewal is out of the scope of this question and answer.

Yet, you can control it in sts.assumeRole by passing "DurationSeconds" (defaults to 1 hr). See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRole-property

For handling session expiration, there are multiple strategies. Like catch the session expiration exceptions to generate new credentials.

If you have an specific case, please create a new question, so we can understand the full program context, scope and concerns.

Answer (score 45):

Found the correct way to do it! Check out this PR:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/1391

Just had to add `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG="true"` to the environment variable along with `AWS_PROFILE="assume-role-profile"`

So it doesn’t require any code update

This is because, the SDK only loads `credentials` file by default, not the `config` file, but since AWS role_arn is stored in the `config` file, we must enable loading the `config` file as well.

Comment: It works for me: with this export, aws JS SDK works like awscli

Comment: This worked for me as well. + for not requiring any code changes, as I'm using the sdk through a third-party library

Comment: if it does not work, make sure to unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE
AWS_PROFILE is the profile you want to assume in your config file

Comment: Thank you! This really helped a lot and did not need any code change.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party, but now the simplest way is probably to use the `AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials`

It refreshes the credentials automatically as well as being chainable in many layers or as here use the default credentials

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials({
  params: {RoleArn: 'RoleARN', RoleSessionName: 'RoleSessionName'}
});
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ChainableTemporaryCredentials.html

Me myself found this question when I wanted to run with an assumed role, so guess it still have some SEO power!

Comment: A code example would also be of a help.

Comment: nice one, in Typescript RoleSessionName is required

Comment: you miss "AWS." before "ChainableTemporaryCredentials({"

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/migrating/notable-changes/, In node js aws-sdk v3, the `AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials` that  [Erik Karlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347012/erik-karlsson) helpfully pointed out has been replaced with `fromTemporaryCredentials` a la

```
import { FooClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-foo";
import { fromTemporaryCredentials } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"; // ES6 import
// const { FooClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-foo");
// const { fromTemporaryCredentials } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-providers"); // CommonJS import

const sourceCredentials = {
  // A credential can be a credential object or an async function that returns a credential object
};
const client = new FooClient({
  credentials: fromTemporaryCredentials({
    masterCredentials: sourceCredentials,
    params: { RoleArn },
  }),
});
```

`masterCredentials` is optional, if you omit it the default credentials will be used to assume the provided role.