# AWS Lambda : Even after STS:AssumeRole was successful, the lambda function still uses the old IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have created a new IAM role, which has access (scan/Query) to specific DynamoDb tables.

I am trying to use STS Assume Role API call from  my lambda function, so that the lambda function gets access to the specific Dynamo Db tables.

The Assume Role call was successful, I got the role ID, AccesskeyId, Secret Access Key and Session Token.

When I make a call from my lambda function, to access the Dynamo DB, I am getting an error

> AccessDeniedException: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::>:assumed-role/ota-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/
>   is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:>:table/<>

My question is, even after the Role Assume call was successful in the Lambda function, why the lambda function was still using the older role to access the Dynamo DB?

I was expecting the Lambda function to assume the new role, but from the logs it looks like, it is using still the older role.

Looks like I am missing some steps in between.

Comment: For a bit more clarification: By roleId, do you mean *AccessKeyId*? Is `ota-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole` the name of older role you mention?

Comment: Yes, ota-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole is my role name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STS `AssumeRole` call, depending how you trigger it, does not automatically refresh credentials in the AWS.config global object of the SDK.

You need to retrieve the access key, session key and session token returned by `AssumeRole` and pass it to your global AWS credentials SDK object.

The exact code will depend on the programming language you are using, here is the doc for Python's Boto3

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

On a side note, I wonder why you do not give permanent access to your DynamoDB table in the Lambda execution role.  Is this to limit the function reach and give fine grained access control at runtime, based on caller's identity ?

Comment: Thanks @Sébastien Stormacqm Yes, I got your point.  I will need to retrieve the access key, session key and session token returned by AssumeRole. Are there any examples for Go language SDK?  About the access to DynamoDb tables, I want to give a fine grained access to  DynamoDB tables based on the callers's identity.

Comment: This is the code snippet I have written in Go and it worked.                                                                                             
roleArn := "arn:aws:iam::AccountID:role/RoleName"
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
creds := stscreds.NewCredentials(sess, roleArn)
dbSession := dynamodb.New(sess, &aws.Config{Credentials: creds})

Comment: I found next links useful and such which еcomplement each other                                  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57456841/9783262 (for Python)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48530115/9783262 (for JavaScript).

I was getting the similar error due to: I didn't pass region_name=<region> into AWS.config.update({...}) and(or) didn't use AWS.config.region = <region>;