# aws sqs getting 'missing credentials in config' error message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I'm using a ec2 instance with a IAM role that gives me all rights to sqs

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "sqs:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

The IAM role has 'ec2' as trust relationship.

On the instance I have a node.js application running with the aws-sdk. I'm using the sqs-consumer library to access the queue.

This is my initialization code:

```
const consumer = require('sqs-consumer');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let options = {apiVersion: '2012-11-05', region:'eu-central-1'};

let sqsClient = new AWS.SQS(options);

        const app = consumer.create({
            queueUrl: 'my_sqs_url',
            region:'eu-central-1',
            handleMessage: handleMessage,
            sqs: sqsIncoming,
            messageAttributeNames:['All']
        });

        app.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

The exact error message I'm getting is: "SQS receive message failed: Missing credentials in config". Which is true, because the IAM role should provide the credentials, according to the docs this should work automatically ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html)). I'm also using this setup for a couple of ecs auto scaling instances and that works without problem, though I'm using a older version of the sdk there (2.324.0).

I'm using aws-sdk version 2.4.19 (latest as of now).

--EDIT-- I forgot to mention, I'm using a windows server ami.

Things I've tried:

- defining hard coded credentials, then it works
- creating a more broad sqs profile (as seen above)
- tried the 2nd answer from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989042/using-profile-that-assume-role-in-aws-sdk-aws-javascript-sdk)

So I'm wondering why this doesn't work, do I need extra setup of the aws-sdk?

--EDIT2-- It turns out I needed more setup code, see [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) for more information.

When I call sqs with the aws-cli I now get the error message: Error when retrieving credentials from Ec2InstanceMetadata: No credentials found in credential_source referenced in profile default

My config looks like

```
# In ~/.aws/config
[profile default]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
credential_source=Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually from the CLI on the machine? I.e. using the AWS to access the SQS queue?

Comment: I've installed the cli and get a different error message, see my 2nd edit for more information.

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure a credential source, or a role_arn, i would remove both of them. And instead doublecheck in the AWS console that the right IAM role is configured for the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I've double checked the role, but it still isn't working. I now use a workaround, I've created a new user and defined a policy for this user, so that I can use the access keys of this user in the default profile. It's one step more than necessary, but at least it's working.